# Which data structure(s) to use to search for an object through one of its two IDs?

Tags: java, data-structures

We have many nodes implemented like this:

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private int id1;
    private int id2;
    private Node next; // or left/right, depending on what you're using.
}
```

1. How to get `name` using  `id1` or `id2` in **average less than O(n)**?
2. How to print all `name`s **in order of** `id2` **in average O(n) or faster**?

I thought of using a hash table ordered with `id1` and a binary search tree organized by `id2`. As a beginner to data structures, I'm still unsure about this approach.

1. Is this the simplest solution, in terms of ease of implementation
   and data structures used?
2. Does using two data structures, both based on the same object, pose  any problems? I'm wondering if "duplicating" data like I am here poses any problems for deleting and inserting, but other problems and solutions to the original questions are welcome too.

Comment: How are the nodes linked to each other?  There's nothing in that object that implies that they are.

Comment: Yep, your proposed solution is probably the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would indeed use a `HashMap<Integer, Person>` to store persons by ID1, and a `TreeMap<Integer, Person>` to store persons by ID2, sorted by ID2.

The first one is O(1) to get the name by ID1. The second one is O(N) for iterating through all the values.

To answer your questions:

1. I think this is indeed the simplest solution
2. Make sure to encapsulate the two maps in an object offering the needed methods and inserting/deleting in both maps at once. Don't expose the two maps to the outside. If you expose an iterator or the collection of values of the second map to the outside, make sure to wrap it using `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()` before returning it, to prevent a modification of the set from the outside.